# Modifying a closed report in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Is it possible to modify a closed report?

```
REPORTS![PIC Sheet]!BoundImage.Picture = "\\Image\Path"
```

This report is never opened.
It is only used to print.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, , , "[Item #]= " Me.ItemNumber
```

I need a way of changing the boundImage based on the ItemNumber.

Comment: What if you open the report, **minimize it**, make your change, save, and close?

Comment: That sounds like what I will have to do. Maybe there is a way to open it and hide it... Thanks.

Comment: I thought mwolfe showed you in your last question how to dynamically change an image path.  Did his code not work the way you wanted?

Comment: Actually, yes there is.  In your Report properties, try setting Visible=No.

Comment: @PowerUser I cannot run mwolfe's code on a closed report...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "[Item #]= " Me.ItemNumber

If Dir("\\Image\Path") = "" Then

    REPORTS![stDocName]!BoundImage.Picture = "\\Image\NoImageExists.jpg"

Else

    REPORTS![stDocName]!BoundImage.Picture = "\\Image\Path"

End If

DoCmd.PrintOut
DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I normally handle images for reports.  There are other methods to accomplish the same goal too, but I find this one is really flexible, and pretty simple.

1)  In the Item table, store the file path to the image you wish to use for that item.  For example Item #1 ImagePath field would be \Image\Item1.jpg or however you wish to handle that.

2)  Pass this image filepath info along into the report query.

3)  Create a hidden textbox to store this filepath for your report, name it txt_ImgPath or something similar

4)  Assuming the image is in the 'Detail' section, you will then add some binding code to the 'Detail_Print' Print Event.  This will dynamically change the picture's path property to the one you have specified.  If no filepath exists the image control is hidden.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
'binds the path to the picture object

    If Len(Me.txt_ImgPath.Value) > 0 Then
        Me.img_Item.Picture = Me.txt_ImgPath.Value
        Me.img_Item.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.img_Item.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Someone might be able to offer more insight if you really need to change it from a report object.  I've never worked with that much.